# What is the meaning of よる in this sentence?

Tags: words

Reading this article I came across よる、but I cannot quite make out its meaning.

副大臣の1人は、ＮＨＫの取材に対し、「事前に全く聞いていなかったので、非常に驚いた。憲法改正や北方領土問題、北朝鮮による拉致問題などを、安倍総理大臣なら前に進められるのではないかと期待していただけに、非常に残念だ。少なくとも任期いっぱいは続けてほしかった」と述べました。そのうえで、「後任の総理大臣の選び方については、安倍総理大臣がいつまで続けられるかや、いつまでに選出しなければならないかにも**よる**のではないか」と述べました。

Researching on my dictionary I came across these words 因る, 寄る and 選る. I am more inclined for the first one since it is for reason.

So:

安倍総理大臣がいつまで続けられるかや、いつまでに選出しなければならないかにも**よる**のではないか
abe prime ministerが　until when can continue や　until whenに must elect かにも　reason no?

I would say it is reason, but I am uncertain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

（～に）[よる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%9B%A0%E3%82%8B/#jn-228572) means "depend (on~)".

「XXはYYによる」- "XX depends on YY"

So your example means:

> 「Regarding 後任の総理大臣の選び方, it would depend on 安倍総理大臣がいつまで続けられるか and also いつまでに(後任の総理大臣を)選出しなければならないか」

> *lit.* Regarding how to pick a new prime minister, it would depend on how long Abe can continue and also by when we need to pick (a new prime minister).